# "Too many arguments" error while running C program on VS Code

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, mingw, settings

So here's the program that I want to run:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Helloworld!");
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the error I get:
[image: Error (too many arguments)]

I seriously don't know why this is happening. A month ago it was working just fine. Whenever I go to Run on VSCode and click "Start Debugging" this is what I get:

[image: Select Enviroment]

Please help.

Comment: Not exactly a solution for your problem but consider using a CMake project and open this in VSCode using "open folder".

Comment: does bash understand `c:\XXXX` paths

Answer (score 3):

There Just change your terminal to Windows PowerShell

1. press CTRL+SHIFT+P
2. Search for “Terminal: Select Default Profile” (previously “Terminal: Select Default Shell”)
3. Select your preferred shell. In my case I selected "Windows PowerShell"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33152255)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the console command line, not the c-code.  As suggested by @molbdnilo, the backslash is an escape character in bash.  In particular, the final backslash in the file path is escaping the quote character, which means the `cd` command is not terminated.  You can either use double-backslashes (to escape the backslash) and/or drop the last backslash in the path.  In bash you can also use forward slash to separate elements in a path to avoid this issue.

Comment: `&&` is good, since it doesn't execute the next command if there is an error. The problem in this case is that there is actually only one command; the `cd`.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, the problem is in the command line, not in your code.

However, the problem is not with g++ or with `&&` (which is good, not bad, since it stops when there is an error), but with your backslash at the end of the directory.
Unlike cmd in Windows, bash interprets `\"` as a literal `"`, not as backslash followed by string delimiter.
This means that `cd` gets the *two* arguments

```
C:\Users\...\Desktop" && gcc hello.c -o hello &&
```

and

```
C:\Users\...\Desktop"hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the Default Profile ( Shell ) to CMD fixes the problem for me. >_<

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ezward, the issue is with your bash command. Suppose you have a file named "a.cpp" at you desktop. Open the terminal in same directory, i.e. desktop and try this command:

```
g++ -o objectFileName sourceFileName
```

For example in this case use:

```
g++ -o a a.cpp
```

This command would produce an object/executable file named "a" for your a.cpp file. Now to run the file enter this command:

```
./objectFileName
```

In this case that will be:

```
./a
```

This will run your code and you would see its output.

Note: I am assuming you're using g++ based compiler in linux/ubuntu. If not, google it on how to install g++ compiler. I hope this link helps:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/481807/how-to-install-g-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

You are using git-bash terminal. So, bash interprets `\"` as a literal `"`, not as backslash followed by string delimiter.

The fix is to use powershell or command-prompt as the default terminal in VSCode instead of bash.

Steps:

1. Open settins.json file (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json).
2. Change `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows"` to either `"PowerShell"` or
   `"Command Prompt"`.

Now, try to execute the script again in VSCode.